# Remove comma in the last element in JavaScript Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to remove comma in the last element in Vue. But I dont know how to do that because the index of the last element is unknown.

```
<td v-if="category.sub_category.length > 0"> 
                      <template v-for="cat in category.sub_category">
                        {{ addComma(cat.subcategory_name) }}
                      </template>
                    </td>

addComma(subCat) {
  let elements = [];
  elements.push(subCat);
  console.log(elements);
  
  if (elements != ""){
    elements += ", ";
  }

  return elements;
},
```

And this is the result of `console.log(elements)` above.

[image]

And this is the result of all code above

[image]

Comment: I recommend taking care of the comas before trying to render the string in DOM

Comment: @Bravo Thats not working. Comma not inserted.

Comment: yeah, because there's a LOT more wrong ... instead of that template, just use `{{category.sub_category.map(({subcategory_name}) => subcategory_name).join(', ')}}`

Comment: This is the most elegant, use CSS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42130196/295783

Comment: and yet, @mplungjan, you can see the criticisms of that solution are valid to a degree

Comment: @Bravo I found a better dupe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
<td v-if="category.sub_category.length > 0">
      {{category.sub_category.map(({subcategory_name}) => subcategory_name).join(', ')}}
</td>
```

I'd be tempted to move it to a computed though - keeps markup clean

```
<td v-if="category.sub_category.length > 0">
      {{subcats}}
</td>


computed: {
  subcats() {
    return this.category.sub_category.map(({subcategory_name}) => subcategory_name).join(', ');
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd be tempted to move that into a computed or a method, personally - I like to leave the markup relatively clean - the question was closed as I posted, so, not sure I can update to show what I mean

Comment: `Cannot read property 'sub_category' of undefined`  when use computed.

Comment: perhaps because at some point, this.category is empty .... @SeadLab - maybe don't use that method then - I've been away from vuejs for a while and there's probably things about your data that are not clear to me

Answer (score -3):

```
elements.join(',')
```

You don't need to create a function for this just use it inside the Vue tag like this

```
{{elements.join(',')}}
```

[image]

Please check in image. I posted answer after checking.

Comment: Not working. I've tried that many times

Comment: @SeadLab Can you please check into the updated answer I added a screenshot. I hope this is enough to prove that my solution will work

Comment: That's not what I mean. It's different. Please check the right answer above!